# how to generate regular expression that doesn't contain specific string at the beginning or at the end?

Tags: regex

I am stuck with creating a regular expression that match any string:
1- contains "<p>\S</p>" in the middle of text
2- doesn't contain <p>\S</p> at the beginning or at the end of the text

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is `\S` any non-space char or you want to literally match `\S` ?

Comment: What kind of reg.exp? Perl? egrep, grep, ECMAScript? Vim?

Comment: \S means any white space and i need PREG... thanks alot for your help

Comment: `\S` is any non-whitespace. `\s` is any whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments it looks like you want to match a single whitespace between `<p>` and `</p>`. If so then you should be using `\s` and not `\S`. `\s` matches any single whitespace character where as `\S` matches any one non-whitespace character.

You can try:

```
(?!^<p>\s<\/p>)(?!.*<p>\s<\/p>$)(?=.*<p>\s<\/p>)
```

The part `(?!^<p>\s<\/p>)` ensure the string does not begin with `<p>\s<\/p>`.

The part `(?!.*<p>\s<\/p>$)` ensure the string does not end with `<p>\s<\/p>`.

The part `(?=.*<p>\s<\/p>)` ensure the string has `<p>\s<\/p>` somewhere.

If you are using this in PHP you should put the regex between a pair of delimiter as:

```
$x="abc <p> </p> def";
$R="#(?!^<p>\s<\/p>)(?!.*<p>\s<\/p>$)(?=.*<p>\s<\/p>)#";                        
$result=preg_match($R,$x); 
var_dump($result); // prints 1.
```